# Combinations of character cells in a data.frame with some conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

i hope someone can help me out with this problem.
Imagine the following character data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(X1=c("a", "b"), X2=c("k", "l"))

df

  X1 X2
1  a  k
2  b  l
```

I want to get all possible combinations between the cells of the columns.

In this case:

a k

a l

b k

b l

My problems are that I dont want to specify how much columns and rows I have and that the code should ignore NA (missing values). EDIT: So in three columns there have to be three element.

```
df <- data.frame(X1=c("a", "b", "NA", "NA"), X2=c("k", "l", "m", "NA"), X3=c("e", "t", "l", "p"))

df

  X1 X2 X3
1  a  k  e
2  b  l  t
3 NA  m  l
4 NA NA  p
```

Another problem is, that I dont want the combinations with a smaler length than the number of columns.
So just for sure some few examples that would fit:

a k e

a l e

b l t

Some examples that wouldn't fit:

a l

NA NA p

The results should then be saved in a character vector. Every element in the vector should be one combination.

Maybe someone has an idea or maybe there is already a thread that may help me out, whereby i didn't find some.

I've tried out different functions like 
combn() or combinations() but either it didn't fit to the problem or i used it in the false way.

EDIT:
The whole supposed Output of the second df:

a k e

a k t

a k l

a k p

a l e

a l t

a l l

a l p

a m e

a m t

a m l

a m p

b k e

b k t

b k l

b k p

b l e

b l t

b l l

b l p

b m e

b m t

b m l

b m p

I hope i didn't make a mistake.

Comment: I'm a little confused by different stages of explanation. Can you please provide the **complete** expected output of the provided dataset `df`?

Comment: I add the whole supposed output and changed the conditions a little bit. I did some errors here, sry for the confusion :( but thanks for your helping here

Comment: Why are rows like `a m e` absent?

Comment: Sry this is exacly the cause why i want to do this automatically, I made a mistake. I hope there arent any mistakes in the explanation and the example any longer :)

Answer (score 0):

The R base function for combinations in a data.frame is `expand.grid`.

```
expand.grid(df)
   X1 X2 X3
1   a  k  e
2   b  k  e
3  NA  k  e
4  NA  k  e
... <lines removed for brevity>
61  a NA  p
62  b NA  p
63 NA NA  p
64 NA NA  p
```

The problem with the example data you provided is that it doesn't have any `NA` values.  When you created the `data.frame`, you put the text "NA" in quotes, which tells R that each column in `df` should contain a character vector with elements equal to the letter "N" followed by the letter "A" rather than the R value for missing data, `NA`  (To be even more precise, each column is a `factor` (an enumerated `vector`, see ?factor in the R help) that includes a level "NA" (a character vector that contain the letter "N" followed by the letter "A") rather than a level for `NA`, but I digress...  Check out the `factorsAsStrings` argument in the R help -- `?data.frame` -- and the topic under  `?factors` for more information.)

Bottom line: to make a data.frame with columns that are `factor`s containing `NA` values, don't use quotes around `NA`:

```
df_NAs <- data.frame(X1=c("a", "b", NA, NA), X2=c("k", "l", "m", NA), X3=c("e", "t", "l", "p"))
```

Now, to solve your problem, we need to remove `NA` from each column in `df_NAs` before calling `expand.grid`.  Remembering that an R `data.frame` inherits from `list` (in other words, an R data.frame **is** a list, where each element of the list contains one column of the `data.frame`), we can use `lapply` to pass each column of the `data.frame` to `na.omit`, the R function that strips `NA` from vectors.  The result will be returned as a list of vectors:

```
list_NoNAs <- lapply(df_NAs, na.omit)

list_NoNAs

$X1
[1] a b
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 3 4
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
Levels: a b

$X2
[1] k l m
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 4
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
Levels: k l m

$X3
[1] e t l p
Levels: e l p t
```

By looking at the first line each item in the list, you can see that the `NA`s have been removed.  The lengths of each element in the list can be displayed with:

```
lapply(list_NoNAs, length)

$X1
[1] 2

$X2
[1] 3

$X3
[1] 4
```

So now you have a `list` of `vectors` of different lengths, because a different number of `NA`s were removed from each column of the `data.frame`.

Fortunately, `expand.grid` operates not just on `data.frame`s, but also on `list`s; it doesn't care if you have different lengths in each element of the list.

```
foo = list(
   letters = c("a", "b", "c"),
   numbers = c(1, 2),
   booleans = c(T)
)

expand.grid(foo)

  letters numbers booleans
1       a       1     TRUE
2       b       1     TRUE
3       c       1     TRUE
4       a       2     TRUE
5       b       2     TRUE
6       c       2     TRUE
```

So, to generate a `data.frame` of the combinations, with `NA`s omitted:

```
df_combos <- expand.grid(lapply(df_NAs, na.omit))

df_combos

   X1 X2 X3
1   a  k  e
2   b  k  e
3   a  l  e
4   b  l  e
5   a  m  e
6   b  m  e
7   a  k  t
8   b  k  t
9   a  l  t
10  b  l  t
11  a  m  t
12  b  m  t
13  a  k  l
14  b  k  l
15  a  l  l
16  b  l  l
17  a  m  l
18  b  m  l
19  a  k  p
20  b  k  p
21  a  l  p
22  b  l  p
23  a  m  p
24  b  m  p
```

Now we need to generate a string from each row of `combos`.  To create a single string from a vector of values, you can use:

```
paste(c("a", "b", "c"), collapse = "")

[1] "abc"
```

So, to create a character vector from each row of `df_combos`, you can send each row of the `data.frame` to the `paste` function using `apply`:

```
apply(combos, 1, paste, collapse = "")

 [1] "ake" "bke" "ale" "ble" "ame" "bme" "akt" "bkt" "alt" "blt" "amt" "bmt" "akl" "bkl" "all" "bll" "aml" "bml" "akp"
[20] "bkp" "alp" "blp" "amp" "bmp"
```

To put spaces between the letters, change the `collapse` argument to `" "`, like this:

```
apply(combos, 1, paste, collapse = " ")

[1] "a k e" "b k e" "a l e" "b l e" "a m e" "b m e" "a k t" "b k t" "a l t" "b l t" "a m t" "b m t" "a k l" "b k l"
[15] "a l l" "b l l" "a m l" "b m l" "a k p" "b k p" "a l p" "b l p" "a m p" "b m p"
```

If you really want to do this all in one line of code, which is entirely unreadable, here it is:

```
apply(expand.grid(lapply(df_NAs, na.omit)), 1, paste, collapse = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
> df <- data.frame(X1 = c("a", "b", "NA", "NA"), X2 = c("k", "l", "m", "NA"), X3 = c("e", "t", "l", "p"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df[df == "NA"] <- NA
> na.omit(object = rev(x = expand.grid(rev(x = df))))
   X1 X2 X3
1   a  k  e
2   a  k  t
3   a  k  l
4   a  k  p
5   a  l  e
6   a  l  t
7   a  l  l
8   a  l  p
9   a  m  e
10  a  m  t
11  a  m  l
12  a  m  p
17  b  k  e
18  b  k  t
19  b  k  l
20  b  k  p
21  b  l  e
22  b  l  t
23  b  l  l
24  b  l  p
25  b  m  e
26  b  m  t
27  b  m  l
28  b  m  p
```

If you need a character vector, you can use `paste`, like @Geoffrey Poole suggested.

Comment: Thanks to you too :)

Comment: Yikes.  My answer was more complex than needed.  Yarnabrina's solution is more elegant, although the last line of that solution could simply be `na.omit(expand.grid(df)))`.  The only disadvantage if Yarnabrina's solution is that `expand.grid` can make an extremely large data frame is `df` has many cases and/or columns.  By removing the `NA` values from the columns first, the resulting dataframe of combinations remains as small as possible.

Comment: @GeoffreyPoole `na.omit(expand.grid(df)))` returns the rows in a different order than in the order OP posted. That's why I reversed twice. I'm not sure how to get OP's order by omitting `NA` values first though.